# Посылка нажатий клавиш приложению

Tags: c#, winapi

Как сделать, чтобы программно посылать нажатие клавишы определённому приложению?

Answer (score 1):

Функцией SendMessage отправляешь сообщение WM_KEYDOWN. Правда для этого надо еще знать Handle окна приложения, в которое отправляешь сообщение, ищется функцией FindWindow. [Windows Messages](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего это делается без Windows API с помощью класса [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx). Если же почему-то нужно задействовать WinAPI, то есть такая функция, как SendInput, которая эмулирует нажатия клавиш, движения и клики мыши.